# Parse.com Android API and Android Dialog

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have placed the parse method inside `onCreate` method. But my problem is how to show the Android Loading... Dialog??

```
Parse.initialize(this, "a", "b");
ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Category");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> catObjects, ParseException arg1) {
        Log.d("Catlength", String.valueOf(catObjects.size()));
        for(int i =0; i<catObjects.size(); i++){
            Log.d("lengthName"+String.valueOf(i), String.valueOf(catObjects.get(i).getInt("Id")));
            Category category = new Category();
            category.Name= catObjects.get(i).getString("CatName");
            category.id= catObjects.get(i).getInt("Id");
            categories.add(category);
        }

        if(categories.size()>0){
            setListAdapter(new CategoryArrayAdapter(CategoryListActivity.this, R.layout.row_category, categories));
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(CategoryListActivity.this, "Our servers are busy. Hit refresh..", 3000).show();
        }

    }
});
```

Everything works fine in the above code but I couldn't figure out how to show the Dialog.

I'm unable to use `AsycTask` also as parse sdk invokes its own thread in the background and before the `findInBackground` execution finishes, the `doInBackground` completes the Asyc thread. That's why I invoked it in the main thread.

As the result I always get no results in my ArrayList.

Can someone please enlighten me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was in the same situation regarding the progress dialog, tried a few tricks and finally just declared a ProgressDialog class member:

```
protected ProgressDialog proDialog;
```

then created two methods:

```
protected void startLoading() {
    proDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    proDialog.setMessage("loading...");
    proDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    proDialog.setCancelable(false);
    proDialog.show();
}

protected void stopLoading() {
    proDialog.dismiss();
    proDialog = null;
}
```

and called startLoading() before the background operation and stopLoading()
inside the background operation after I got the the results.

```
startLoading();
    ParseUser.logInInBackground(userName.getText().toString(), hashedPass, new LogInCallback() {
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
            if (user != null) {
                Log.d(Constants.TAG, "User Loged in.");
                ParseManager.sCurrentUser = user;
                stopLoading();
                finish();
            } else {
                stopLoading();
                invalidCreds();
            }
        }
    });
```

if you want to use AsyncTask don't call findInBackground() you can use find().
you can check it out in the api [https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#find()](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#find%28%29)

hope this helps.

Comment: I have used something similar but using `AsycTask`. Thanks for the answer anyway :)

Comment: I tried this way but I believe the progress dialog is using up the UI thread, no? I tried using the AsyncTask, but it's at least 4x slower

Comment: This makes the download very slow... not really a workable solution since it runs on the UI thread

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to get the progress of both uploads and downloads using ParseFile by passing a ProgressCallback to saveInBackground and getDataInBackground. For example:

```
byte[] data = "Working at Parse is great!".getBytes();
ParseFile file = new ParseFile("resume.txt", data);

file.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
  public void done(ParseException e) {
    // Handle success or failure here ...
  }
}, new ProgressCallback() {
  public void done(Integer percentDone) {
    // Update your progress spinner here. percentDone will be between 0 and 100.
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm not reading or saving file. just reading plain data. I'll try `progresscallback()` anyway

Comment: seems it'll not workwith `findInBackgroun` https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/class-use/ProgressCallback.html

Comment: I won't downvote since this is technically correct but this does not work due to the functionality being broken.